# Урок, урочище

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Пока писала про Черную речку, возник еще один вопрос. Интересует слово "урочище". Википедия определяет урочище как любую часть местности, отличающуюся от другой местности. Тот же самый Чернореченский каньон в Крыму.
Но вот откуда само это слово "урочище"? Если исходить из логики словообразования, это просто оооочень длинный урок)))) А если серьезно, есть ли связь между словами "урок" и "урочище" и какая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово действительно родственно словам урок, урочный (в смысле "заранее условленный"), + -ище - как в словах, обозначающих место, например кладбище, лежбище, стойбище, пастбище, стрельбище, логовище, токовище, зимовище и т. п.

Урок =  у + рок (рек, речь) - нечто уговоренное, условленное (М. Фасмер). Уроками также называли порчу, сглаз, "отметки, знаки" нечистой силы на человеке. Урочищами (от урочить - "нарекать, назначать впредь, предсказывать") называли всякий природный знак, межевой признак (речку, гору, овраг, лес и т. п.)

Answer (score 0):

"Урок — фиксированный размер дани или, возможно, каких-либо работ, которые должны были быть выполнены к определённому сроку. Введение уроков являлось частью административной реформы, проведённой княгиней Ольгой в X веке, когда она разделила Новгородскую землю на погосты и установила уроки" Похоже и Урочища - это земли на которых собиралась дань (урок).